# Vlookup returning #N/A in VBA code

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I hope you can help. I have created some VBA code and what it does is it allows a user to click on a command button witch opens a dialog box and from here a user selects Excels sheets and a Vlookup executes. The sheets save and close with the vlookup complete. The issue is that I am getting #N/A returned by the Vlookup. I am unsure if I am doing the vlookup on an incorrect column or if it is a formatting issue.

I have supplied pics for better understanding. In Pic 1 you can see that column L has the #N/A. Column J 'Expense Request Number' is the column that I am using to perform the Vlookup.

In Pic 2 you can see that column T also contains 'Expense Request Number' and it is likewise involved in the Vlookup.

I am just trying to find out how many 'Expense Request Number' are present in the colorful sheet that are also present in the less colorful.

My code is below as always any and all help is gratefully appreciated.

Pic 1

[image]

Pic 2 
[image]

CODE

```
Sub Add_consent()

    'Definition of used variables
    Dim Directory As String 'Directory for inputs and outputs
    Dim Consent_folder As String 'Directory for inputs and outputs
    Dim inputFile As String 'Input file name
    Dim currentInput As String 'Input file name
    Const DELIMITER As String = "|" 'Values delimiter
    Dim OutputFile As String 'Output file name
    Dim lngCount As Long    'selected files count
    Dim wbkOutput As Workbook 'output workbook
    Dim wbkTemp As Workbook 'temporary workbook
    Dim myWkBook As Workbook 'Input Workbook
    Dim Consent As Workbook 'Consent file
    Dim Consent_name 'new opened file
    Dim myWkSheet As Worksheet 'Input Worksheet
    Dim sheetNum As Long 'Variable for sheet number
    Dim sheetNames() As String 'output worksheet sheet names
    Dim sheetInterfaceName 'Sheet name representing DID interface
    Dim Active As Worksheet 'Active worksheet
    Dim intLastRow As Long 'Last row element
    Dim Error_Codes As Worksheet ' Sheet containing error codes
    Dim myRecord As Range 'Record for output
    Dim myField As Range 'Cell value for output
    Dim nFileNum As Long 'Variable for file number
    Dim sOut As String 'Text to be written into file
    Dim invalidDelete As String 'Case of invalid delete attempt
    Dim sheetIndex As Long ' Current sheet index
    Dim Selected As Long '
    Dim rwCount As Long 'Number of current sheet rows containing data in tracking file
    Dim colCount As Integer 'Number of current sheet columns containing data in tracking file
    Dim extraCol As Integer 'Number of current sheet columns containing data in tracking file
    Dim indexRow As Long 'Row index
    Dim helpRow As Long '
    Dim AddIn As Integer
    Dim selectedCount As Integer
    Dim int1 As Long
    Dim int2 As Integer
    Dim int3 As Integer

    'General application settings
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'Turns off switching to exported excel file once it gets opened
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'Turns off automatic alert messages
    Application.EnableEvents = False '
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False 'Turns off the "update links" prompt

    'User prompt, choose Master file
    MsgBox "Choose Master File"

    'Alternative way to open the file
    Dim fd As FileDialog
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    fd.AllowMultiSelect = False

    'Assign a number for the selected file
    Dim FileChosen As Integer
    FileChosen = fd.Show
    If FileChosen <> -1 Then
    'Didn't choose anything (clicked on CANCEL)
        MsgBox "No file selected - aborted"
        End 'Ends file fetch and whole sub
    End If

    Dim fss As Object
    Set fss = CreateObject("Scripting.FilesystemObject")
    inputFile = Dir(fd.SelectedItems(1)) 'parses only the name of file
    Directory = fss.getParentFolderName(fd.SelectedItems(1)) & "\" 'parses only directory of the file

    'Open Master file .xlsx spreadsheet
    Set wbkTemp = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Directory & inputFile)
    'Set wbkTemp = Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)

    'Get number of columns in the Master file
    colCount = wbkTemp.Sheets(1).Cells(9, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    'Get the number of rows in the Master file
    intLastRow = wbkTemp.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Row

    'Set Transaction Id format to number
    wbkTemp.Sheets(1).Range(wbkTemp.Sheets(1).Cells(10, 10), wbkTemp.Sheets(1).Cells(intLastRow, 1)).Select 'Specify the range which suits your purpose
    With Selection
        Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
        .Value = .Value
    End With

    'Prompt user for the second file
    MsgBox "Select file(s) containing R & D information"

    'Open R&D file dialog
    Dim filedial As FileDialog
    Set filedial = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)

    Dim chosen As Integer
    chosen = filedial.Show
    If chosen <> -1 Then
    'Didn't choose anything (clicked on CANCEL)
        MsgBox "No file selected - aborted"
        End 'Ends file fetch and whole sub
    End If

    'Number of selected files
    selectedCount = filedial.SelectedItems.Count

    'Extra variable
    AddIn = 0

    For Selected = 1 To selectedCount
    'Open file with Consent info
    Consent_name = Dir(filedial.SelectedItems(Selected))
    'Consent_folder
    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=Consent_name, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar:="|"
    Set Consent = Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)

    'Number of rows in consent file
    rwCount = Consent.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    'Specify the column to paste data
    extraCol = colCount + AddIn + 1

    '1)
    'VLOOKUP across spreadsheets for consent data
    'wbkTemp.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Copy
    'wbkTemp.Sheets(1).Cells(1, extraCol).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    'wbkTemp.Sheets(1).Cells(1, extraCol).Value = "Consent"
    'With wbkTemp.Sheets(1)
        '.Range(.Cells(2, extraCol), .Cells(intLastRow, extraCol)).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(.Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(intLastRow, 1)).Value, Consent.Sheets(1).Range("B:J"), 8, False)
    'End With

    '2)
    'VLOOKUP across spreadsheets for consent data
    'wbkTemp.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Copy
    'wbkTemp.Sheets(1).Cells(1, extraCol).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    'wbkTemp.Sheets(1).Cells(1, extraCol).Value = "Consent"
    'With wbkTemp.Sheets(1)
    '    '.Range(.Cells(2, extraCol), .Cells(intLastRow, extraCol)).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(.Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(intLastRow, 1)).Value, Consent.Sheets(1).Range("B:J"), 8, False)
    '     For int1 = 2 To intLastRow
    '        if Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(.Cells()))
    '
    '     Next int1
    'End With

    '3)
    'VLOOKUP across spreadsheets for consent data
    wbkTemp.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Copy
    wbkTemp.Sheets(1).Cells(1, extraCol).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    wbkTemp.Sheets(1).Cells(9, extraCol).Value = "Expense Request number"
    With wbkTemp.Sheets(1)
        .Range(.Cells(10, extraCol), .Cells(intLastRow, extraCol)).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(.Range(.Cells(10, 10), .Cells(intLastRow, 10)), Consent.Sheets(1).Range("A:AE"), 20, False)
    End With

    'Close the file with consent information
    Consent.Close

    'Loop again for next file
    AddIn = AddIn + 1
    Next Selected

    'Deal with N/A values
    With wbkTemp.Sheets(1)
        For int1 = 2 To intLastRow
            For int2 = 1 To selectedCount
                If Not Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(.Cells(int1, colCount + int2).Value) Then
                    .Cells(int1, colCount + 1).Value = .Cells(int1, colCount + int2).Value
                End If
            Next int2
        Next int1
    End With

    'Remove extra columns
    With wbkTemp.Sheets(1)
        .Columns(fnColumnToLetter_Split(colCount + 2) & ":" & fnColumnToLetter_Split(extraCol + selectedCount)).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    End With

    'Save and close the new workbook
    With wbkTemp
        'Save and close the new workbook
        .SaveAs Filename:=inputFile
        .Close True
    End With

    MsgBox "Available R & D information added"


End Sub

Function fnColumnToLetter_Split(ByVal intColumnNumber As Integer)
    fnColumnToLetter_Split = Split(Cells(1, intColumnNumber).Address, "$")(1)
End Function
```

Comment: I dont see any `VLookup` in the code, they're all commented out.

Comment: The `VLOOKUP` is: `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(.Range(.Cells(10, 10), .Cells(intLastRow, 10)), Consent.Sheets(1).Range("A:AE"), 20, False)` - It looks as though you're looking up a range as your first parameter of the `VLOOKUP`, this needs to be a single cell or a value as opposed to a range of values.

Comment: Hi Jordan: Thank you for the response. I have made a few changes but I am now getting #REF where the 'Expense Request Number' is present and #N/A where it is not the changes I have made are here `Consent.Sheets(1).Range("T2:T200"), 20, False)` is there a way to correct the #REF and #N/A happening

Comment: Hi Jordan. I have figured it out. My range was not high enough only putting the lookup to T200 meant I was missing out on a lot of numbers. If i extend the range to T2000 or beyond it brings back results. With this I have solved my problem and I am happy to accept your answer. Much respect from Dublin :-)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what A.S.H said in the comments a usual problem with vlookup is that the first column of the vector has to be sorted in ascending order.
In that case Expanse Request Number